# Samsung T5 portable SSD opens very slow

Tags: samsung

I recently got T5 SSD and decided to pick some files from it on Ubuntu. First I thought it doesn't work for some reason, and checked usb-devices command to see if it appears. And yes it does, right away. However it didn't show in file manager, until after about 5 minutes it magically popped up. Tried again and same thing, takes 3-5mins before it shows. Any idea why and how to make it speedier for my Ubuntu to open?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same model portable SSD and it had the same problem that it didn't show up in the file manager or in Disks when I plugged it in, but it always showed up when I plugged it into my phone. In my case the problem was purely mechanical because the cable wasn't plugged in firmly into the USB port. Because this portable SSD is small it should be put in a place where it  won't be accidentally moved around which could cause the cable to be dislodged.

Comment: In case this is relevant to your question, the Samsung T5 portable SSD is shipped with disk encryption software which I do not use on this device.